# Why does Debian ship Google API keys with Chromium?

Tags: debian, chrome, api

I have a file called `/etc/chromium.d/apikeys` which has the following contents,

```
# API keys assigned to Debian by Google for access to their services like sync and gmail.
 
export GOOGLE_API_KEY="AIzaSyCkfPOPZXDKNn8hhgu3JrA62wIgC93d44k"
export GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_ID="811574891467.apps.googleusercontent.com"
export GOOGLE_DEFAULT_CLIENT_SECRET="kdloedMFGdGla2P1zacGjAQh"
```

Why does Debian ship Google API keys though to begin with? You don't need an API to go to gmail.com? What happens if I nuke this file?

You can see it's part of upstream chromium,

```
$ dpkg -S /etc/chromium.d/apikeys
chromium: /etc/chromium.d/apikeys
```

What part of chromium functionality requires these keys?

Comment: `What happens if I nuke this file?` try it - you can always just move the file out of that folder, and if things break, move it back

Comment: @JaromandaX I don't want to assume if Chrome boots up things work. It could be making calls to Google's services that I just so happen not to be using at the point in time I conclude things are working, or worse, Google may obtain a new unique key which would otherwise identify me. Better to ask, imho.

Comment: https://salsa.debian.org/chromium-team/chromium/-/blame/bullseye/debian/etc/apikeys -> https://salsa.debian.org/chromium-team/chromium/-/commit/ee87a9416a0c9e522b914f86a3127eb5893a4768 -> https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=748867 -> https://lwn.net/Articles/570485/

Comment: @A.B I submitted that as an answer (though I formatted it properly)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is for the Signing into Google with Chromium which gives you the option to upload things like your saved password to the Google Cloud.

> The key in question allows access to nine separate **Google services including Spelling, Suggest, Translate, Geolocation, Safe Browsing, and so on.** While some of those features could be considered optional, losing them would certainly degrade users' experience compared to Chrome browser users—or even Firefox users—in many cases. It's a little strange to see a feature added that requires a magic key in order to use it, but the restrictions on what can be done with the APIs and keys makes it all the more worrisome.

You can read more about this on lwn.net, [*"Chromium API keys on Debian"*](https://lwn.net/Articles/570485/). This was added after bug 748867 [*"Missing API keys, some features of chromium are disabled"* was filed](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=748867) with [this patch](https://salsa.debian.org/chromium-team/chromium/-/commit/ee87a9416a0c9e522b914f86a3127eb5893a4768)

---

Thanks to [A.B. in the comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/251756/a-b) with all the links.